# Creating default relational objects for a many-to-many relationship, and keeping changes in my database context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, relational-database

What I want to do: When a user selects a product, populate a data grid with every Product. If that Product / Event combination have an associated EventProduct, fill in other pieces of the data grid with that data. If not, create a new EventProduct and default all properties to 0. On saving the event, if the EventProduct properties have changed or been populated, save that EventProduct to the DB as a new EventProduct.

My current approach: 
I have three classes: Event, Product, and EventProduct as defined here (truncated).

```
public partial class Event
{
   [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
   public Event()
   {
      EventProducts = new HashSet<EventProduct>();
   }

   [Key]
   public int index { get; set; }

   [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
   public virtual ICollection<EventProduct> EventProducts { get; set; }

}

public partial class Product
{
   [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
   public Product()
   {
      EventProducts = new HashSet<EventProduct>();
   }

   [Key]
   public int index { get; set; }
   [StringLength(200)]
   public string name { get; set; }

   [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
   public virtual ICollection<EventProduct> EventProducts { get; set; }
}

public partial class EventProduct
    {
        public EventProduct()
        {
            Event = new Event();
            Product = new Product();
            quantity_allocated = 0;
            quantity_sold = 0;
            quantity_sampled = 0;
        }
        public int index { get; set; }
        public int EventID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public int? quantity_allocated { get; set; }
        public int? quantity_sold { get; set; }
        public decimal? quantity_sampled { get; set; }

        public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm populating the table by querying and joining my Products to my EventProducts, and creating a new Associative Object which has a Product and an EventProduct in a one-to-one relationship. I'm setting my itemsource equal to the following:

```
public static List<ProductEventProduct> GetProductEventProduct(Event e, DatabaseModel dbContext)
{
   var query = from product in dbContext.Products
               join eventProduct in dbContext.EventProducts
                     on new { pIndex = product.index, eIndex = e.index }
                        equals new { pIndex = eventProduct.Product.index, eIndex = eventProduct.Event.index } into temp
               from eventProduct in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new ProductEventProduct
               {
                     Product = product,
                     EventProduct = eventProduct
               };
   var dataSource = query.ToList();
   foreach (ProductEventProduct entry in dataSource)
   {
         if (entry.EventProduct == null)
         {
            entry.EventProduct = new EventProduct()
            {
               EventID = e.index,
               ProductID = entry.Product.index,
               Product = entry.Product,
               Event = e
            };
         }
   }
   return dataSource;
}
```

And when I have a single, manually input (direct into my data source) EventProduct it works as intended, and users can edit the Allocated amount (sold and sampled are locked in this view):
[image: Image of correctly populated data grid on event window]

My problem is with saving. Right now I'm iterating through each row of the data grid, and if it's been changed or if the value is not null, create an EventProduct from that and add that EventProduct to my Database Context:

```
List<Associations.ProductEventProduct> entries = (List<Associations.ProductEventProduct>)EventProductDataGrid.ItemsSource;
IEnumerable<Associations.ProductEventProduct> changedEntries = entries.Where(association =>
   association.EventProduct.quantity_allocated != 0 ||
   association.EventProduct.quantity_sampled != 0 ||
   association.EventProduct.quantity_sold != 0);
foreach (Associations.ProductEventProduct entry in changedEntries)
{
   // if there are no event products in the database that have the same product and event, it's new so save it to DB
   if (!(dbContext.EventProducts.Any(ep =>
      ep.EventID == entry.EventProduct.EventID && ep.ProductID == entry.Product.index)))
   {
      dbContext.EventProducts.Add(entry.EventProduct); // line where I get the error described below
      dbContext.SaveChanges();
   }
   else // if it is an EventProduct which exists in the database already
   {
      EventProduct modifyEvent = dbContext.EventProducts.Single(ep => ep.Event.index == entry.EventProduct.Event.index && ep.Product.index == entry.Product.index);
      modifyEvent.quantity_allocated = entry.EventProduct.quantity_allocated;
      modifyEvent.quantity_sampled = entry.EventProduct.quantity_sampled;
      modifyEvent.quantity_sold = entry.EventProduct.quantity_sold;
   }
}
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

But when adding my EventProduct to my DBContext, I get the error, "'A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: A primary key property that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be changed when the dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set to the association's principal object. The principal object must be tracked and not marked for deletion.'". Which doesn't make sense to me, since both its references to Product and Event are populated, valid, and correct in my debugger.

I've been stuck on various pieces of this issue for days now and I know that my approach is wrong, any advice would be enormously appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your problem is that the `EventProduct` you are adding to your `DbContext` refers to an `Event` or `Product` (or both) that already exist in the database but are not currently being tracked by the `DbContext`. When calling `dbContext.EventProducts.Add(entry.EventProduct);` it has the effect that it's trying to add the `entry.EventProduct.Event` and `entry.EventProduct.Product` in the `DbContext` as if they are new entities.

If you know that `entry.EventProduct.Event` and `entry.EventProduct.Product` already exists in the database, then you can add them to the change tracker letting EF know that they already exist and haven't changed:

```
// Let EF know the entities already exist
dbContext.Set<Event>().Attach(entry.EventProduct.Event);
dbContext.Set<Product>().Attach(entry.EventProduct.Product);

// Now add the EventProduct letting it refer to the existing Event and Product
dbContext.EventProducts.Add(entry.EventProduct);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**Note**: as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.attach?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#remarks) the entities you attach will be given the state `Unchanged` which means if you do have changes to the `Event` or `Product` that you want to update in the database you should instead use [DbContext.Entry()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.entry?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) and set the returned [Entry.State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.state?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Infrastructure_DbEntityEntry_State) to `Modified`.

Comment: thank you this sheds a lot of light on the issue. Now I've created a method in a context where the Event is constant, loops through all Products, and foreach Product checks to see if there is an associated EventProduct. If there is, it adds the EventProduct to a list. If there isn't, it creates it with the property defaults (and the Event and Product) and adds that to the List the method returns. It works better than anything else I tried, but on adding new EventProducts to my dbContext I get Referential Integrity Constraint Violations. Should I check if the Event/Product exist?

Comment: @rook218 if you don't know whether the Event and Product already exists in the database when adding the EventProduct you would need to check (`dbContext.Events.Any(...)` etc.) first, yes. But I would suggest trying to design your system such that you know this up-front. E.g. you should be able to answer "no" to the question: will I ever create a new EventProduct that will refer to an Event or Product that does not already exist?

Comment: In the context I'm running this in, I definitely know that both the Products and the Event exist. My problem was mainly that I was creating most of my form from my Event object, then separately creating 8 (or so) EventProducts, and trying to save them separately. It's working much better now that I'm ONLY using my Event and Event.EventProducts properties.

Comment: I resolved this by not being a dumb dumb and actually using the MVVM design rather than trying to skirt around it and handle my business logic in my UI components.